# Angle between two vectors given information about other vectors

Tags: vectors

Find the angle between (defined as x) **p** and **q** given that:

**p=a+b, q=a-b**, angle between **a** and **b** is pi/6 and the lengths of **a** and **b** are root 3 and 1 respectively.

I got:
$$cos(x)=\frac{p.q}{|p||q|}=\frac{(a+b).(a-b)}{|a+b||a-b|}=\frac{3}{|a+b||a-b|}$$

I am unsure on how to simplify the denominator. I guess I need to use the angle pi/6 as I haven't used it as of yet?

**Edit: My lecturer's answers say the answer is arccos(2/root7) ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 
$$\vec a\cdot \vec b=|\vec a||\vec b|\cos(\pi/6)=\sqrt 3\cdot 1\cdot (\sqrt 3/2)=3/2,$$
you'll have
$$\vec p\cdot \vec q=(\vec a+\vec b)\cdot (\vec a-\vec b)=3-1=2,$$
$$|\vec p|^2=|\vec a+\vec b|^2=|\vec a|^2+2\vec a\cdot\vec b+|\vec b|^2=3+3+1=7\Rightarrow |\vec p|=\sqrt 7,$$
$$|\vec q|^2=|\vec a-\vec b|^2=|\vec a|^2-2\vec a\cdot\vec b+|\vec b|^2=3-3+1=1\Rightarrow |\vec q|=1.$$

Since 
$$\cos(x)=\frac{\vec p\cdot\vec q}{|\vec p||\vec q|}=\frac{2}{\sqrt 7\cdot 1},$$
you'll have
$$x=\arccos(2/\sqrt 7).$$

Answer (score 1):

Using your notation:

$$(a+b)(a-b)=||a||^2-||b||^2=3-1=2$$

so I can't understand how you got there $\;3\;$. Also

$$||a+b||^2=(a+b,a+b)=||a||^2+||b||^2+2(a,b)=4+2(a,b)\\
||a-b||^2=(a-b,a-b)=||a||^2+||b||^2-2(a,b)=4-2(a,b)$$

and finally, using the definition of cosine:

$$\frac{\sqrt3}2=\cos\frac\pi6=\frac{(a,b)}{||a||\cdot||b||}=\frac{(a,b)}{\sqrt3}\implies (a,b)=\frac32$$

Well, now take it from here...

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$|a+b|=\sqrt{(a+b)\cdot(a+b)}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab}=\sqrt{|a|^2+|b|^2+2ab}$$

Comment: Useful hint, thank you!